# How to print all set bits of a negative integer

Tags: java, bit

```
 while (n != 0) {
      System.out.print(n & 1);
      n  = n >> 1;
 }
```

The above code in Java leads to an infinite loop, if n = -1.

How do I get it to print negative integers?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `>>` operator is a "sign-extended" right-shift operator, which means that if the top bit in the original value is set, the bits that are "shifted in" are 1. That keeps the sign of the result the same, basically.

You want the `>>>` operator (the *unsigned right shift* operator), which always "shifts in" 0 bits, even if the top bit was 1.

See [JLS section 15.19](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.19) or the [Java tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html) for more details.